# AWT Multiple File Upload Applet

Tags: java, applet

> I use "File Upload Applet" for uploading file, but when we run html file its show error message

```
Error is :-
java(TM)is out of date
Using JRE version 1.7.0_51-b13 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
User home directory = /home/east
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to <n>
```

Comment: @AndrewThompson Actually I might withdraw that suggestion and replace it with another one: *google for "java(TM)is out of date"*. There seem to be specific issues in Chrome.

Comment: sir i updated but error is same

Comment: sir, have you googled around? You may need to install JavaFX2.

Comment: live demo could show error i had seen multile demo like :http://postlet.com/example/